# How to give sleep in qml

Tags: qt, qml

When I press the button now it instantly goes to the next page. Is it possible to give this loading.gif a sleep of 5 seconds?

I have tried to give it a `duration: 5000` but then it gives an error

---- FULL CODE UPDATED  ----

Login.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.15

Component
{
    Rectangle
    {
    
        Rectangle
        {
            anchors.fill: parent

            // Timer for Creating delay
            Timer 
            {
                id: timer
            }

            function delay(delayTime,cb) 
            {
                timer.interval = delayTime;
                timer.repeat = false;
                timer.triggered.connect(cb);
                timer.start();
            }

        ColumnLayout 
        {
            // Some other items.

            Button
            {
                onClicked:
                {
                    backend.inloggen(email.text, wachtwoord.text, dropdown.currentText)

                    delay(5000, function() 
                    {
                        loading_container.visible = true 
                    })

                    stack.push(btnHomepage) 
                }
            }
    
            Rectangle
            {
                id: loading_container
                visible: false

                AnimatedImage
                {
                    source: "./images/loading.gif"
                }
            }
        }
        }
    }
}
```

Error: `Login.qml:170: ReferenceError: delay is  not defined`

Sadly updating the the QtQuick nad QtQuick.controls update wasn't the solution

Comment: Why deliberately add a delay to a UI? If the underlying code is actually taking 5 seconds, I would suggest to create some signal that emits when ready, upon which you open the page (I mean it can be more/less on other computers)

Comment: where did you put Timer and delay and where is Button? Do you put them in a separate qml File???

Comment: `import QtQuick 2.12` and `import QtQuick.Controls 2.12` or latest version that you have.

Comment: I have put the code in the same file. (Login.qml). I will try to use 2.12. I will upload the hole file. maybe then its easyier to find the problem

Comment: could you put your project in github? and add its link here?

Comment: If you give me an second i will paste a github link here.

Comment: @Minimumspace , I found it , I comment `ColumnLayout` and `Component` and Try it and it works . and also put Timer and delay function in top not inside Rectangle.

Comment: I will waiting for you github , there I can help you easier.

Comment: https://github.com/Kw1c-OverdijkJarno/login.qml.git   this should work i will test what you said about the coloumlayout and component. Don't mind the weird tabbing i don't know what that is.

Comment: I see 404 page in link that you send

Comment: could you try the link again i have changed it to public. 

https://github.com/Kw1c-OverdijkJarno/login.qml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you update the question, Try this :

[Component](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html) encapsulated QML types with well-defined interfaces.

**the way that you use it is wrong.**

**The way that you use Function in your program is also wrong.**

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.12

Item {
    width: 640
    height: 480

    Timer
    {
        id: timer
    }

    function delay(delayTime,cb)
    {
        timer.interval = delayTime;
        timer.repeat = false;
        timer.triggered.connect(cb);
        timer.start();
    }


            Rectangle
            {
                anchors.fill: parent

                // Timer for Creating delay


//            ColumnLayout
//            {
                // Some other items.

                Button
                {
                    onClicked:
                    {
//                        backend.inloggen(email.text, wachtwoord.text, dropdown.currentText)

                        delay(5000, function()
                        {
                            loading_container.visible = true
                        })

//                        stack.push(btnHomepage)
                    }
                }

                Rectangle
                {
                    id: loading_container
                    visible: false

                    AnimatedImage
                    {
                        source: "what ever is your source path"
                    }
                }
            }
//    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

you can create delays by using [Timer](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-timer.html) here is your code, I add one function that creates delay it gets duration like 5000 means 5 seconds, and one function that will be connected to Timer.
This function acts like a singleshot.

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    // Timer for Creating delay
    Timer {
        id: timer
    }
    function delay(delayTime,cb) {
        timer.interval = delayTime;
        timer.repeat = false;
        timer.triggered.connect(cb);
        timer.start();
    }
    Rectangle
    {
        id: loading_container
        anchors.fill: parent
        color: "#d71616"
        anchors.rightMargin: 0
        anchors.bottomMargin: 0
        anchors.leftMargin: 0
        anchors.topMargin: 60
        visible: false


    }

    Button {
        id: button
        x: 0
        y: 0
        width: 151
        height: 62
        text: qsTr("Click me ")

        onClicked:
        {

            delay(5000, function() {

                loading_container.visible = true

            })



        }


    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the fast reaction! Do i have to place this in the main.qml or at the page where i have the button?

Comment: I don't have your gif source so I create Red Rectangle as an example but you can use it in your code. for creating delay or single-shot you should use Timer.in c++ QTimer has this but in qml I do it with that function

Comment: @Minimumspace , For use delay you need to call the delay function.

Comment: So i have tried to use your code. I only get an error: `Login.qml:170: ReferenceError: delay is not defined`. Look code updated have i done anything wrong? (placed everything on one page) first I make the timer function then the button and at last the rectangle.

Comment: you put some  part of code , it works for me , create a new project and add my code there then test it , if you see that error again its relate to your qt version and installation if not then you have mistake in adding code to your project.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the button doesn't have access to the Delay function, hence the reference error you get
Simply move the function to the button and the Timer in the root item

Comment: Seems like I was late. @Parisa.H.R. explained it even better with the code example